# Extending elasticsearch boolquery with script score

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm using elasticsearch java client with code to search my index:

```
BoolQuery.Builder compoundQuery = new BoolQuery.Builder()
                .should(q -> q.match(m -> m.field("title").query(phrase).boost(100f)))
                .should(q -> q.match(m -> m.field("analyzedTitle").query(phrase).boost(70f)))
                .should(q -> q.match(m -> m.field("titleAggregation").query(phrase.replace(" ", "")).boost(50f)))
                .should(q -> q.prefix(m -> m.field("titleAggregation").value(phrase.replace(" ", ""))
                        .caseInsensitive(true).boost(30f)))
                .should(q -> q.wildcard(m -> m.field("titleAggregation").wildcard("*" + phrase.replace(" ", "") + "*")
                        .caseInsensitive(true).boost(30f)))
                .should(q -> q.prefix(m -> m.field("title").value(phrase).caseInsensitive(true).boost(0.2f)))
                .should(q -> q.prefix(m -> m.field("tokens").value(phrase).caseInsensitive(true).boost(0.2f)));

        var query = NativeQuery.builder()
                .withQuery(b -> b.bool(compoundQuery.build()))
                .withMaxResults(10);

        elasticsearchOperations.search(query.build(), Doc.class);
```

My documents have field named 'boost' with values (3,2,1) I want to extend that query by script score and recalculate scores from that query using 'boost' field value (score * boost). I have tried adding:

```
                .should(q -> q.scriptScore(m -> m.script(fn -> fn.inline(InlineScript.of(fn2 -> fn2.source("_score * doc['boost'].value"))))));
```

But that produced `co.elastic.clients.util.MissingRequiredPropertyException: Missing required property 'ScriptScoreQuery.query'`.

I'm unable to find any examples and java api docs are really basic. Does anyone have any ideas how to achive that ?

Comment: I didnt solve that problem but I did found a better solution. For simple boost by field We can use something called rank feature, and its easier to use it with builder above:

    `.should(q -> q.rankFeature(m -> m.field("boost").boost(10f)));`
Its also faster than script score and recomended for simple values unless we are doing more advanced scoring.
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html